# Click listener class, which will be created later

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to find out if its possible to create a class clicklistener. When i create a div listener, i can first add the listener and afterwards i can create the div.

So i want to create the listener first and later i add the class. Is it possible?

html:

```
<div>
    <div id="1">
        <div id="2">
            <!-- will be created.. -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(".welcome").click(function() {
    alert("Hi there");
});

// Later the class album will be loaded
// When you put it above it will work..
welcome = document.getElementById("2");
welcome.innerHTML = '<div id="3" class="welcome"> Hello</div>';
```

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5vYb/9/) to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes...use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event delegate...

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next.

try this

```
 $(document).on('click','.welcome',function() {
    alert("Hi there");
 });
```

even more better is if u attached the event to closest element...in your case that is div with id #2 `<div id=2`>

```
$('#2').on('click', '.welcome', function() {
   alert("Hi there");
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/n5vYb/10/)

Comment: tnx, its working :D. I have to find out more about Jquery :D.

Comment: Note that attaching the delegate event to `document` is what `live` used to do, and is the reason it's now deprecated. You should attach the event to the closest static element, in this case `#2`.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this. In jQuery this pattern is known as a delegated event. You can attach the click handler to the `#2` element, which will be available once the `.welcome` element is appended to it. Try this:

```
$('#2').on('click', '.welcome', function() {
    alert("Hi there");
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n5vYb/11/)

Note in your fiddle I also amended the plain javaScript to use jQuery methods. If you've got them, you may as well use them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, using [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$(document).on('click', '.welcome', function(e) {
    alert("Hi there");
});
```

I've used the `document` to attach the delegated event handler to because that will pick up **all** elements that match the `.welcome` selector, regardless of where they are on the page. Ideally you'd use the closest static element that will contain all the elements you want to match, though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delegate to the nearest existing parent which is available in the dom when page was ready:

```
$('div[id="2"]').on('click', '.welcome', function(e) {
    alert("Hi there");
});
```